# How do I use the primary key of a table in a fact table? [PowerDesigner]

Tags: primary-key, powerdesigner

I have to create a database model in university and there are several tables. I want to add all of the primary keys of these tables to a fact table.

But somehow I'm not able to check the "Primary key box" when using it in both tables with the same name.  It looks like this:
[image: It looks like this]

Is there anything in the settings I have to change or am I just doing something wrong?

I've seen another thread on here, where people said, that two boxes under Tools > Model Options > Data Item have to be unchecked, but I can't find them - might be, because the question was more than 4 years old and some things changed since then.

However, I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you in advance.

I expected to be able to check the primary key box in both, the normal and the fact table.